# Make message with two separate parts in title and text below

Tags: html, css

For a message system, I need to have a message that has a title bar that's all one piece, with info regarding who posted it on the left side, and then a badge on the far right. Below this, Full box for text. [Here's an example of the kind of messages I'm looking for.](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/sc2-strategy/446960-mass-reaper-tvp)

I've tried using divs and tables, but am completely new to CSS and feel like I'm slamming my head against a wall. Since my HTML and CSS are sad attempts, feel free to use barebone examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/v36eG/1/) << *please see the updated fiddle at the end of the answer*

Try this and let us know:

**HTML**

```
<div class="msgBox">
    <div class="msgHeader">
        <div class="msgTitle">
            Title Here <small>date of post</small>
        </div>
        <div class="msgBadge">
            badge here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="msgBody">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, similique, quidem amet quia consectetur rerum ducimus blanditiis voluptatum labore animi neque cum repudiandae delectus placeat ut! Non, nihil animi temporibus.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.msgBox{
    width: 100%;
}
.msgHeader{
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.msgTitle{
    float:left;
}
.msgBadge{
    float: right;
}
.msgBody{
    color: #e00;
}
```

UPDATE:

update 1 on fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/v36eG/2/

update 2 on fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/v36eG/3/

Comment: Sensible class names that describe what something **is** are far better than names that describe where you want it. +1

Comment: This is definitely the basics of what I'm looking for, the issue I'm running into is background coloring and bordering. Could you edit it to make the msgHeader have one solid background across and a border encompassing it, and the text below having a similar border and different color?

Comment: @Befall, styling is totally up to you, you can play around with it.. **However**, I've already updated the code with more styling and you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/v36eG/2/

Comment: If HTML5 elements can be used it would help with accessibility. Using divs for everything will make this very difficult for users with accessibility issues to use.

Comment: @SULTAN, one more question: how can I get rid of the space between the header and body? I'd like just a 1px border between them and am not sure what property would stick 'em together.

Comment: @Nicknameless You're right, however Befall as he described himself is completely new to CSS & I am sure he want something straight-forward to help him understand how things works. In addition to that, a good portion of the HTML5 is still not fully supported in all browsers http://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-33/firefox-28/ie-11/opera-20/safari-7.0.html

Comment: Nevermind, figured out using negative margin values! :)

Comment: @Befall add `float: left;` in the `.msgHeader`

Comment: Being new to CSS is all the more reason to share the best practice instead of the quick fixes.

Comment: @Nicknameless we can debate on this forever, and using divs is not quick fixes.  Plus, I am sure, all of us will be thankful to see you sharing the best practice example

Comment: @Befall also, add `float-left` to the `.msgBody` class ::: updated fiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/v36eG/3/

Comment: @SULTAN take a look at my answer with codepen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bkqlm/) example of an HTML5 version that would be much more accessible.

HTML:

```
<article>
  <h3>
    <span class="user">
      <img class="icon" src="http://placehold.it/20x20" alt="user icon image | username">
      <span class="user_name">
        User Name
      </span>
      <span class="user_location">
        UserCity
      </span>
    </span>
    <span class="post_info">
      <span class="post_timestamp">
        Month, 30, 2014 00:00
      </span>
      <span class="post_count">
        Post: 0000
      </span>
    </span>
    <span class="post_badge">
      <a href="#">Badge</a>
      <a href="#">Badge</a>
      <a href="#">Badge</a>
    </span>
  </h3>
  <div class="post_content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac lacus risus. Donec in molestie augue, eu convallis ante. Sed quis molestie mauris, vel pulvinar nunc. Cras sit amet lobortis sem, et placerat leo. Curabitur id rutrum metus, eget lobortis nisl. Ut lobortis malesuada leo eu eleifend. Suspendisse laoreet ipsum nec interdum adipiscing.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac lacus risus. Donec in molestie augue, eu convallis ante. Sed quis molestie mauris, vel pulvinar nunc. Cras sit amet lobortis sem, et placerat leo. Curabitur id rutrum metus, eget lobortis nisl. Ut lobortis malesuada leo eu eleifend. Suspendisse laoreet ipsum nec interdum adipiscing.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ac lacus risus. Donec in molestie augue, eu convallis ante. Sed quis molestie mauris, vel pulvinar nunc. Cras sit amet lobortis sem, et placerat leo. Curabitur id rutrum metus, eget lobortis nisl. Ut lobortis malesuada leo eu eleifend. Suspendisse laoreet ipsum nec interdum adipiscing.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
article {
 background-color: grey;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;

}
article h3 {
   background-color: red;
   padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}
article h3 span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
article h3 span.post_badge {
  float: right;
}
article div {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: This solution makes more sense from an accessibility and clean code perspective. Headers should be with `<h1> - <h6>` tags and the individual blocks of your page should be set inside of the appropriate  `<div>` type tag (he uses `<article>` in his example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left;` and `float:right;`

E.G.:

```
.msgTitle {float:right;}
.msgDate {float:left;}
```

with something like this:

```
<div>
    <span class="msgTitle">Some line of text</span>
    <span class="msgDate">Date info</span>
</div>
```

Edit: check out the example in this JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Incredulous/MyG5r/

Comment: I've tried several bits with that, but I need a more solid example. Would this be using two divs? Or two table parts?

Comment: Added an edit of my original answer with an example.

Comment: Ah, using <span>, didn't really know how those were used. Cool, I'll work with this and see if I can get it pretty, thank you.

Comment: I chose the `<span>` element because of its inherent lack of automatic property assignment. You could change what element you use if you so desire. Good luck.